# Nginx/Django File Upload Permissions

Tags: python, linux, django, nginx, file-permissions

Today I noticed that whenever I upload a file through my Django site the file is uploaded with the file permissions 0600 meaning whenever a non root user wants to view the file (nginx) a 403 is shown.

This only started happening today from what I can tell. I have checked both the file_upload_permissions and file_upload_directory_permissions in the Django settings file and they are both set to 0644.

I haven't done any Linux/Django updates recently so that shouldn't be the cause, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have recently switched to Python 3, please take a look at [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers) for a reference to octal literals in Python 3. Changing your settings as follows should fix it:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```

[This](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html) is also helpful in writing Python 2-3 compatible code.

Comment: Sorry but I have only used Python 3 for the entirety of this project. I will try adding in the 'o' though and see if that helps, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I see, did you give this a try? Just asking to make things more clear for the readers.

Comment: I will shorty and let you know the outcome, I will update my question as well just in case people miss this.

Comment: It Worked!!! Thank you so much, who knew a simple 'o' could make such a difference haha

Comment: I didn't quite get it, how it relates to Django ? I mean that in their documentation they say that `0o644` should be by default.

Comment: @ArtemBernatskyi, as stated in their documentation, Django aims to be compatible with different versions of Python. So let's say if you are working with Python 2.7, you can either have 0o644 or 0644 but if the underlying Python installation is version 3, you have to go with 0o644. In any case, using the new representation is the safest and therefore strongly recommended. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thumbs up!! Great. This was really helpful. It took me whole day to find the solution.