# Django: When a user uploads media to my site, it is owned by the server's root user. How do I change this?

Tags: python, django, unix

I am unsure of what code you guys would want me to upload, but please ask away if you need any and I will upload it!

When a user uploads media/files to my website, the root user becomes the owner of the file. This prevents the user from being able to open and view the media they uploaded, because it is not owned by the proper user on my server.

I have a user that runs my Django application instead of the root user. The person who uploaded the media can access it once I manually go into the server and change the ownership to that media file that was uploaded, to the server user which runs my Django application.

How can I get this to, by default, upload the file to the ownership of the server user running Django??

I was thinking of setting up a cron job to run every-so-often (this would be terrible for scaling) so I can change the ownership of the media without having to physically going in the server and do it myself.

**Edit**

I want to clarify.

A user is someone who has created a profile on my website. They go on their profile and upload a file or an image to my server and it is stored under the `media_root` using a form submission.

My server is running Django, and *django_user* is the owner of Django and it’s files. However, when a user uploads a file/photo using the form submission, it is placed under the ownership of my servers *root* user.

I need the ownership to be under *django_user* so that site users can see their uploads without me having to manually change the file owner to *django_user*. Right now, they are getting a permission error because *root* is not who is serving up Django.

**NOTE**: *django_user* is the one running Django. This didn't seem clear.

**Temporary Solution**:

A temporary solution comes in the form of ErikR's answer. It is not what I was looking for, but it does help me out a little. His solution allows users to view their photo/file they've uploaded without having to wait for me to change the owner/permissions.

However, it does still cause files to be uploaded as root. But it is a temporary workaround for the permissions issue, NOT the owner issue.

His answer (place in base settings): FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644

Comment: So you want the image to be owned by the uploader ?

Comment: How are you (or your user) uploading the media to your site? If you upload it by Django, it should be owned by user, under who is the Djago running - and therefore the Django should be able also read it and serve it as document. If you use other method, then it should be set up to upload the files for Django under the required user, not as a root. I am usually uploading files else via web(Django) so no problem there, or scp as desired user, not a root ... Generally uploading as a root should be done only by root and only for system files, not by users and user files.

Comment: @Moha369 i have updated my question for clarification. gilhad please review the same edit. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You may set the permissions in `settings.py`:

#### Assigns read and write to user, and read-only to group:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```

[Nginx/Django File Upload Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570808/nginx-django-file-upload-permissions)

Comment: He literally says that the object itself is not owned by the uploader, so yours will only help the root user

Comment: This may be a temporary solution... although I do want to make sure the owner is my *django_user* when the file is uploaded. Thank you for taking the time to post this

Comment: You say that your "**server** is running Django and _django_user_ is the owner of Django". Which user is running Django? Your root user or _django_user ?

Comment: @ErikR, I just updated my question again to make it clear. *django_user* is the one running Django.

Answer (score 0):

> My server is running Django, and django_user is the owner of Django and it’s files. However, when a user uploads a file/photo using the form submission, it is placed under the ownership of my servers root user.

If Django is really running as `django_user`, then it cannot create files owned by `root`, and it cannot change the ownership or permissions of files owned by root.

Therefore, we must assume that your "form submission" must be implemented by something other than Django.  Possibly it is the host webserver ... though that *shouldn't* be running as `root` either.

There are two ways you could address this:

- You could change the code that is implementing the form (as `root`) to change the ownership of files after they are uploaded.
- You change your system's architecture so that the form us run as the `django_user` user.

---

If the form is actually implemented in Django, then that is evidence that Django is not running as `django_user`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. What would you suggest for tracking down what `server user` the `form` is being submitted under? `nginx conf` has `django_user` as the user running it, currently.

Comment: Use `ps` / `pstree` / etc to figure out what the actual user id of the processes are.